# How can I restrict which sockets receive realtime publish updates in Sails.js?

Tags: security, socket.io, sails.js

All of Sails' publish methods take an extra parameter which allows me to tell Sails not to publish to one specific socket.  What I'm not seeing is a way to restrict a whole class of sockets from receiving updates.

In my application, users manage a lot of personal information including things like names and addresses.  When a person record is created or updated, I don't want that information broadcast to every single socket connected to the system.  The only users who should receive the updates are users associated with the group that owns the record in question.

I need to be able to:

1. Review the session associated with each socket.
2. Determine if the user associated with that socket is a member of the group that owns the created/modified person record.
3. Only publish to the sockets that fit said criteria.

Does Sails support filtering on the server side?  If that kind of filtering is left up to the client, then I can't secure my data.